# how do i add validation to this method in angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Hi I have a controller where the post method still takes place even when an error comes up to say the fields weren't completed. You refresh the page and entry goes from the view.

```
$scope.create = function () {
                    var account = Account.save($scope.account);
                        modalService.success('Success! Your Account has been created!');
                        $uibModalInstance.close(account);    
            };
```

I have tried a few things, but they haven't worked. I need the method to return false if the form hasn't been filled in or fields are missing. Basically a 422 error; as the post goes to an api endpoint.

The example above is my code and need to add some validation into it, but just don't know where to start.

Really tired and need some help quickly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all you need to add validation to your form fields using required, and then before calling the save function, call the validate method on submit and then return true or false to submit the form and call the function.

Comment: Hi, is it ok if you validate before sending the request to the api endpoint ? If so, you should check out the documentation for ng-message https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait till that save method actually complete an ajax and then respond to you

```
var account = Account.save($scope.account).$promise.then(function(){
    //success function
    modalService.success('Success! Your Account has been created!');
    $uibModalInstance.close(account);    
}, function(error){ //error function
    //here is the place you can do error handling part.
    console.log('Error occured, do handle it here.')
});
```

**Update**

If you wanted to make sure before submitting form user should be enter a all form fields and all. Then you could take use of angular form validation feature. Where you can disabled form submit button till all form `required` fields are filled up & have `required` attribute over the fields which are required.

Comment: @Ben glad to know that. Thanks :-)